# Add double qoutation at specific location in words using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to clean words :

```
{"id":1, "name":Robert}, {"id":2, "name":"Skylar"}, {"id":3, "name":"Ben"}, {"id":4, "name":Anne}
```

become have double quotation for all words after `"name":` like below:

```
{"id":1, "name":"Robert"}, {"id":2, "name":"Skylar"}, {"id":3, "name":"Ben"}, {"id":4, "name":"Anne"}
```

How do I clean this using sed?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like JSON, don't parse JSON with regex !

Comment: yes, it's json. I need to clean it since using mongoexport

Comment: Better would be to fix the tool that produces the invalid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
sed 's/\("name":\)\([A-Za-z]\+\)/\1"\2"/g' file
```

- `\("name":\)` (ERE: `("name":)`) matches `"name":` and places it in capture group 1,
- `\([A-Za-z]\+\)` (ERE: `([A-Za-z]+)`) matches a group of chars comprising letters A to Z and a to z and places it in capture group 2,
- `\1` and `\2` expand to contents of capture groups.

Comment: thank you very much! it's solved. Thanks for the logic behind the code too :)

Answer (score 0):

If your data in `d` file, try gnu sed:

```
sed -E 's/("name":\s*)"?([^"}]+)"?\s*\}/\1"\2"\}/g' d
```